# ImageMagick convert is not creating an animated gif

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a folder containing a series of PNG files named forGif001.png forGif002.png ... and I am trying to convert them to an animated gif. The command I am using is `magick convert -delay 1000 *png -loop 0 newGif.gif` where the `delay` value is supposedly in milliseconds (a delay of 1000 being 1 second therefore) but I have tried it with smaller values such as 1 just to be safe.  However, the gif it creates is just a still image of forGif001 and it never cycles to any of the following pictures. I am not getting any errors or warnings. I installed image magick a few hours ago so I imagine the issue is not stemming from an outdated version.

Comment: each of the (24) .png files are about 8.6 kb while newGif.gif is 580 kb, so I imagine that means SOMETHING is happening? Why else would newGif be so much larger in size than forGif001

Comment: With Imagemagick 7, use magick not magick convert. However, that will not affect your issue.  What do you get from `magick -version`? Delay defaults are in ticks (1/100 sec). Some viewers impose a minimum delay limit. Do you get any error messages? Try adding -adjoin before the output GIF.